# Change alias in ToQueryString() method EF Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I need to use SQL queries and run them without Linq and EF Core on that project database has been written and managed with EF Core & Linq

```
testdb.Test.Include(a => a.Childs)
           .Select(x => new { x.Name, Child = x.Childs.FirstOrDefault()})
           .Where(a => a.Name == "" && a.Name == "").ToQueryString();
```

Result of this command is :

```
SELECT [t].[Name], [t1].[Id], [t1].[Name], [t1].[ParentId], [t1].[Test]
FROM [rest].[test2] AS [t]
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Name], [t0].[ParentId], [t0].[Test]
FROM (
SELECT [t2].[Id], [t2].[Name], [t2].[ParentId], [t2].[Test], ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER(PARTITION BY [t2].[ParentId] ORDER BY [t2].[Id]) AS [row]
FROM [rest].[test] AS [t2]
) AS [t0]  WHERE [t0].[row] <= 1
) AS [t1] ON [t].[Id] = [t1].[ParentId]
```

Now that result alias not equals with navigation properties name and I want to use `for json auto` to map that result in json format then deserialized to C# object.

Problem shown here I can't change alias in EF Core...

Comment: Why do you need to change EF Core's SQL or even reuse it? You have objects returned by your query - use them and project to everything that can be mapped to JSON in any manner.

Comment: project migrate from Cloud db to multi-tenant database and my tenants have their own server i dont have their connection string and i Communicate with their db with middle-ware i written with Socket and i send Sql Queries that execute them and return results as json

Comment: Maybe you need something like [Remote.Linq](https://github.com/6bee/Remote.Linq) It will serialize Linq query and return result back, but for sure EF should be on the other side also.

Comment: Yeah But imake that things custom for us :D

Comment: If you have written middleware - you can inject EF, Isn't? Also this is big backdoor, you can execute ANY SQL, which may delete data, with Remote.Linq, you will get only read access.

Comment: I wrote that things likd remote.linq

Comment: Nice to hear, I'm glad that helped you somehow )

Comment: Company that work with that at that time have very useless and silly terms to create something to work with database without dbConnection and create custom client handler that handle efcore linq code's with socket LoL. @SvyatoslavDanyliv